# Cordova doesn't create app icon in Emulator

Tags: cordova

I have created many test apps, this time i wanted to begin my real project, and I went to emulator (through, cordova emulate android), and through the emulator, i moved the mouse pointer on my previous application icon and uninstalled it, now that i follow same old steps, my new application icon does not appear in the emulator, despite the fact that everything is good, the app runs, it succeeds.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried and run in real mobile device.?

Comment: Though my answer to this question is not the exact answer, but it worked for me and so I answered my own question. please check it.

Comment: i prefer  instead of dragging .apk to your emulator use real android device to connect with you machine and start adb service for connect your for developing and start developer option in your device and test in real environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason, when i was running this of cordova commands:

```
cordova build android
cordova emulate android
```

it was not updating the existing copy of the application in the emulator, what i did was, when emulator was up and ready, i was dragging the .apk file from this path:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Workshop\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk
```

and file name is:

```
android-debug.apk
```

and then it was updated with the fresh copy. the best option is to use the USB debugging, thats like putting the app to work.